# Can't connect to VPN through ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-web-services

I have created a VPC (private and public subnet) and VPN connection with the AWS wizard.

Unfortunately, I can't connect to the host in the VPN outside AWS. When I try, I get a timeout.

I have created an ec2 instance in the private subnet which normally see the VPN. I have checked this link (https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpn-tunnel-phase-1-ike/) and all the configuration seems good in VPN side.

Just one thing, we have configured only one tunnel, we can't configure two tunnel. In the AWS console, I see two tunnels down (see attachment). So I have three questions:

Why I have two tunnels by default ? Which tunnel is used by default ? How can I debug the connection to see where I have the problem ?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: "I see two tunnels down (see attachment)."  I don't see an attachment.  Is there an image you meant to include?

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot it. It's ok now

Comment: You have not mentioned what hardware or software you have deployed on *your side* of the VPN connection.  That is where you will do most of the troubleshooting.  You can't provision two tunnels? Why not?  That is the standard configuration, for redundancy.  But, if you get either tunnel to come up, the traffic will automatically select that tunnel. Clearly, though, if both are down, then all is not right with your setup. Please provide more about the specific configuration you are trying to use.

Comment: It's a Cisco VPN3000, I have no more info because I don't work on this VPN, I have on amazon side for my project. What can be wrong on VPN side ? I use the amazon file